# ImportError: cannot import name 'S3Error' from 'minio.error'

Tags: python, importerror, minio

```
ImportError: cannot import name 'S3Error' from 'minio.error' (/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/minio/error.py)
```

I have tried to import the `minio.error` on Python 3.10, which returns this error. How can I resolve this?

Comment: Did the answer solve your issue? If so, consider accepting it (see [What should I do when someone answers my question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers)).

Answer (score 2):

As you can see in the [source code](https://github.com/minio/minio-py/blob/7.0.0/minio/error.py), the `S3Error` class exists since minio version 7.0.0.

Solution: update your minio to version 7.0.0 or higher.